# Cannot find tld file, tld is in shared lib

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, rad, websphere-portal

I am trying to publish applications onto portal server, the pu8blication fails as it is unable to find a .tld file in the WEB-INF dir.

The tld is file is actually not there in the WEB-INF dir, we use the tld file for 20 more applications, so we put that in a shared lib with some other jars.

How do I tell RAD to check the shared lib when it is trying to publish it to my server ? or How can i tell it to ignore the tld file, because my application loads the tld files when it starts up.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your .tld files in a folder named tlds under the META-INF folder of your java project. Then the project should be checked in the Web libraries tab of the Java EE Module Dependencies of your web app project.

Comment: How can I be aware of all these folder structures in a Java EE? I am not able to find a unique definition in my web searches, e.g. in a project I am working on, the "tlds" folder is a child folder of "WEB-INF" and I am a bit confused.

Comment: I learned how to do it  looking at other jar files but according to the text below, the tlds folder may not be necessary.
Taken from JSP 2.1 spec section JSP.7.3.4:
The container searches for all files with a .tld extension under /WEB-INF or a subdirectory, and inside JAR files that are in /WEB-INF/lib. When examining a
JAR file, only resources under /META-INF or a subdirectory are considered.

Answer (score 1):

This is probabaly not the answer you want, but here it is.

To solve a similar problem (same, but not with servlets, not portlets) I created a directory named ".../WEB-INF/tld" in my project and copied the tld file out of the shared lib into my project.

While I do not recommend this as a solution, it is the only solution I could get to work with WAS 6.1

Comment: This behavior is by the JSP 2.0 spec - looking at all TLD files under WEB-INF and its subdirectories.